# How to install pry on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, pry

First off, I have read through previous questions and answers and have not found anything that solves my issue.

On the official Pry website, http://pryrepl.org/, it says that this will install pry for you: "gem install pry" however, I've tried doing that and get this error "ERROR: While executing gem ... (Zlib::DataError) invalid code lengths set"

Looking into more answers on how to install this, I've found suggesting to type in "gem install pry-windows", still no results.

Can someone take a step back to *before typing that code* and let me know what requirements are needed beforehand?

I have ruby installed and I generally use cmd to run my ruby files. I also have irb (Interactive Ruby) and have tried running the above commands there, also to no avail.

Where am I supposed to be running these commands "gem install pry", cmd or irb? Also, do I need to download any files beforehand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of digging around, I just figured it out.

I had to install RubyGems first. http://rubygems.org/pages/download When doing this for windows, follow the regular instructions, but then when you run "ruby setup.rb" make sure that you opened the command line using "Run as Administrator".

Hope this helps anyone else figuring out how to download Pry.